# Change focus between web inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, focusout, jquery-focusout

In a JavaScript/jQuery web context, having:

- Two form text input fields, A and B, that are enabled
- The input fields should be disabled if none of them has focus

I.e. by jQuery's focusout function to check when both A and B loses focus works fine, but when A loses focus to B (tab or by selecting B), I am not able to check if B as gained focus yet, since A's focusouts before the focus change is completed.

How can I check by a focusout or equal that both A and B has lost focus when switching between the input fields?

Example:

Disables the input fields when both looses focus, but unfortinately also when switching between them - which is not the intention.

```
$('input').focusout(function() {
    if ($(':focus').length === 0) { // does not count the other input yet
        $("input").prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hbypowv4/

Comment: Show us some code of what you have so far

Comment: How can you `focus` on one of those `input` fields if both of them are `disabled`; or have I overlook some of the requirements?

Comment: One of them is loaded with autofocus

Comment: You can't focus on disabled fields, so there is no mean of onFocus event on that element...

Comment: The input fields are not disabled by default

Comment: Updated with example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`MouseEvent.relatedTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget) to check if A loses focus to B

> The MouseEvent.relatedTarget read-only property is the secondary
>   target for the event, if there is one

https://jsfiddle.net/hbypowv4/2/

Comment: You're welcome! Unfortunately, there seems to be a bug in Firefox (Gecko): https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=962251

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with window.setTimeout() like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').focusout(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        if ($(':focus').length === 0) {
            $("input").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    }, 5);
  });    
});
```

Comment: This is subject to a race condition though.

Comment: @kaarel Yes, I know. But I consider it a hack, since I down't know if everything is ready after 5ms.. however it might be what I'll end up with.